# Braintree - Callback When Payment Method Changes

Tags: paypal, braintree

Is there a callback in the Braintree drop-in for when the user changes the payment method? I see there is `onPaymentMethodReceived` but it's called when the form is submitted. I need a callback when the payment method changes.

Basically, what I need is a way to know when the user selects "PayPal" as the payment method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I'm a developer at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Right now we don't have a callback for the Drop-in that is called when the payment method is updated. If your main usage of the Drop-in is to be SAQ A compliant, it is worth it to check out [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/guides/hosted-fields/overview). Hosted Fields let you custom build your own payment method forms, with the actual form input handled on Braintree servers. This also allows you to customize your integration more than the Drop-in, which would let you build your own payment method picker, and implement any callbacks necessary to detect a change in payment method selection.